# Nuxt, DjangoAPI - Call is returning a CORS Error

Tags: django-rest-framework, cors, nuxt.js, nuxt3, djoser

i want to build my first Website with Nuxt and a Django API.

Can someone maybe explain me why the "submit()" function works but the "update_labels()" function returns a CORS Error?

I really tried to fix it myself but can't figure it out.
Would be really nice if someone can explain & help me to understand my mistake.

**Images: [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyEFZ.png)**
**[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okkoJ.png)**

```
methods: {
        async submit() {
            const { data: token, error } = await useFetch('auth/jwt/create', {
                method: 'POST',
                baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify(this.formData),
                onResponseError({response}) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + response.status)
                }
            })
            if (!error.value) {
                localStorage.setItem('token', token.value.access)
                return token.value.access
            } else {
                console.log(error)
            }
        },

        async update_labels() {
            const { data: user_data, error } = await useFetch('auth/users/me', {
                method: 'GET',
                baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'JWT ' + (localStorage.getItem('token'))
                },
                onResponseError({response}) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + response.status)
                }
            })
            
            if (!error.value) {
                console.log(user_data)
            }
        }
    }
```

Tried different CORS Settings in the Django setting.py -> nothing happens -> tried blank whitelist -> submit() also gets CORS error so it works?

Tested the Endpoint with Postman -> no problems

Had a weird error where i had to change localhost:8000 to 127.0.0.1:8000. Wanted to do this with the origin but coudn't figure out how to do it

django - settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    'djoser',
    'corsheaders',
    'accounts',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

Comment: Have you installed cors in your django project and put the cors app in installed apps in setttings.py file? Additionally,  post your settings.py file

Comment: Yes tried also with whitelist & allowing all. I put the settings.py in the post.

Comment: You'll have to post the settings.py. CORS errors are usually due to backend configuration. But your case is interesting, one usually gets CORS error for post requests rather than get requests

Comment: I updated the post with the settings.py

Comment: I've seen the issue...The documentation states that CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before any middleware that can generate responses such as Django’s CommonMiddleware or Whitenoise’s WhiteNoiseMiddleware. If it is not before, it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these responses. So cut the last two lines, delete line 3 and paste the two lines in your MIDDLEWARE array

Comment: Ohh... how did i not see this in the setup guide... thanks alot!

Answer (score -2):

CORS is handled differently when doing a POST and a GET . You have probably not setup CORS to accept all *.
Also note in Django The documentation states that CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before any middleware that can generate responses such as Django’s CommonMiddleware or Whitenoise’s.

From GPT "
there can be differences in CORS handling between POST and GET requests.

Simple Requests vs. Preflight Requests: CORS handling can be different for simple requests (e.g., simple GET requests) and preflighted requests (e.g., requests with custom headers, or non-simple methods like POST). Simple requests are requests where the browser sends a request without first checking with the server (preflight) if the actual request is allowed. Preflighted requests are sent before the actual request to confirm with the server if the actual request will be permitted.

CORS Headers: Both GET and POST requests can trigger CORS headers, but the circumstances under which they do so can differ. Simple requests (including simple GET requests) are subject to fewer CORS headers than preflighted requests. Preflighted requests include additional headers like Access-Control-Request-Method and Access-Control-Request-Headers.

Content-Type Header: If you're sending data with a POST request and the Content-Type header is something other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain, the browser will automatically treat it as a preflighted request, regardless of the HTTP method.

Headers and Payload: While both GET and POST requests can have headers, POST requests typically carry a payload (request body) which may contain data. Handling the payload introduces additional considerations in CORS.

Security Implications: Because POST requests can modify data on the server, they are often subject to stricter security restrictions. Browsers may require the server to implement more stringent CORS configurations for POST requests compared to GET requests.

In summary, while CORS principles apply to both GET and POST requests, the actual CORS behavior can differ depending on whether the request is simple or preflighted, whether there's a request body, the Content-Type header, and the security implications of the HTTP method. It's important to be aware of these differences and ensure your server is properly configured to handle CORS for the specific types of requests your application makes."